# How can I sort files by name between two separator?

Tags: c

I use `scandir` with `alphasort`. But I need to sort by name between two `separator`.

Alphasort sorting like this, because of first date string:

```
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702133000_20200702183000_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702143000_20200702153000_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702153000_20200702133000_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702163000_20200702143000_000_2000.tar.gz
```

I need to sort with second date like this:

```
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702153000_**20200702133000**_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702163000_**20200702143000**_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702143000_**20200702153000**_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702133000_**20200702183000**_000_2000.tar.gz
```

I can do with ls/sort command like this:

```
ls /dir/*.tar.gz | sort -k5,5 -t '_'
```

How can I do that with C?

Comment: Maybe you can execute the command you found with ls and read the output

Comment: use `qsort` and define the function to compare to call `strcmp` or `alphasort` from the desired offset

Answer (score 2):

Here an example where I use `qsort`, in the function comparing the strings I bypass the 32 first characters because you want to compare without considering them :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  /* compare strings bypassing the 32 first characters */
  return strcoll(*((char **) a) + 32, *((char **) b) + 32);
}

int main()
{
  const char * v[] = {
    "FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702133000_20200702183000_000_2000.tar.gz",
    "FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702143000_20200702153000_000_2000.tar.gz",
    "FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702153000_20200702133000_000_2000.tar.gz",
    "FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702163000_20200702143000_000_2000.tar.gz"
  };
  
  qsort(v, 4, sizeof(char *), compare);
  
  for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
    puts(v[i]);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702153000_20200702133000_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702163000_20200702143000_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702143000_20200702153000_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702133000_20200702183000_000_2000.tar.gz
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note I do not compare the strings between the two separators but after the first because that does not really change the result.

I also suppose the separator is at the index 31, if this is not the case just use `strchr` to find the fourth '_' rather than to add 32.

Using that principle you can do :

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int filter(const struct dirent * d)
{
  /* may be check also this is a file */
  return !strncmp(d->d_name, "FILENAME_", 9) &&
    (strlen(d->d_name) > 32);
}

int compare(const struct dirent ** a, const struct dirent ** b)
{
  return -strcoll((*a)->d_name + 32, (*b)->d_name + 32);
}

int main()
{
  struct dirent **namelist;
  int n = scandir(".", &namelist, filter, compare);
  
  if (n == -1) {
    perror("scandir");
    return 0;
  }
  
  while (n--) {
    puts(namelist[n]->d_name);
    free(namelist[n]);
  }
  free(namelist);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ touch FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702133000_20200702183000_000_2000.tar.gz FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702143000_20200702153000_000_2000.tar.gz FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702153000_20200702133000_000_2000.tar.gz FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702163000_20200702143000_000_2000.tar.gz
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702153000_20200702133000_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702163000_20200702143000_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702143000_20200702153000_000_2000.tar.gz
FILENAME_000_XXX_20200702133000_20200702183000_000_2000.tar.gz
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sort -k5,5 -t '_'
> ```

A tedious improvement to the other great answer by @bruno would be to find the 5th field separated by `_` character in the string and compare only it.

```
// finds 5th field separated by _ in field and saves length in length
const char *find_5th_arg(const char *str, size_t *length) {
     for (int i=0;i<4;++i) {
         str = strchr(str, '_');
         if (!str) return NULL;
         ++str;
     }
     const char *end = strchr(str, '_');
     if (!end) end = str + strlen(str);
     *length = end - str;
     return str;
}
// function to be passed to qsort
int compare_5_5__(const void * a, const void * b) {
      const char *x = *(const char **)a;
      const char *y = *(const char **)b;
      // extract 5th fields
      size_t x_5th_len;
      const char *x_5th = find_5th_arg(x, &x_5th_len);
      size_t y_5th_len;
      const char *y_5th = find_5th_arg(y, &y_5th_len);
      // printf("%.*s %.*s\n", x_5th_len, x_5th, y_5th_len, y_5th);
      // if both input files have 5th
      if (x_5th && y_5th) {
          // get the shortest
          size_t lenmin = x_5th_len > y_5th_len ? y_5th_len : x_5th_len;
          int ret = memcmp(x_5th, y_5th, lenmin);
          if (ret) return ret;
          // if length differ, put the shortest in front
          if (x_5th_len > y_5th_len) return 1;
          if (x_5th_len < y_5th_len) return -1;
     }
     // fallback to compare lexicaligraphi-something-ly the whole line
     return strcmp(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Well, you have to find 5th too to know where does the 5th field ends. : )